# Cannot get form to validate

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

The problem is nothing validates. I can leave the form empty and it gives no alert

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {

        var x = document.forms["myform"]["fname"].value;

        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("Enter your certificate address first.");
        } else if(!x.match(/facebook/g) || !x.match(/access_token/g)) {
            alert("Invalid certificate address, please try again...");
return false;
        }
)

</script>

<form name="myform" action="welcome.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

not sure what  is wrong with this. looks pretty straitforward

Comment: Change ) to } at the end.

Comment: oh i accidentally used a ) instead of } before </script>

Answer (score 2):

Missing your last end bracket. Changes **)** to **}**